# Transform an object to another, LINQ-style

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

LINQ allows to elegantly transform the collection returned by a method to a different collection, i.e.

```
var x = SomeMethod().Select(t => new { ... });
```

Now, is there a concise way in C# to transform the return value of a method without introducing an intermediary variable? Declaring and invoking a lambda seems to work but is quite ugly:

```
var x = new Func<T, object>(t => { return new { ... }; })(SomeMethod());
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this the best one can do with C# today?

Comment: Why would you think that code is ugly? The only thing I would do is swap `var` by the actual return type and specify the object type (if applicable) but otherwise I think that's acceptable code.

Comment: [Tuple deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#deconstruction) is not fully general, but applicable in some scenarios. In general, I really don't see what's wrong with (gasp!) writing *two lines* of code rather than one (`var x = SomeMethod(); var y = new { x.foo, x.bar, ... }`). There's no tax on lines, or variables, and it's not like anything shorter isn't using intermediaries under the covers anyway.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I fully agree. I'm asking this question mostly out of intellectual curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) followed by [`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx) to sequence of one item created from the result of calling `SomeMethod`, as follows:

```
var x = Enumerable.Repeat(SomeMethod(), 1).Select(r => new {...}).Single();
```

If you do it a lot, you can make a generic extension method for this:

```
static class MyExtensions {
    public static TRes Transform<TSrc,TRes>(this TSrc src, Func<TSrc,TRes> selector) {
        return selector(src);
    }
}
```

Now the syntax becomes very simple:

```
var res = SomeMethod().Transform(x => new { ... });
```

Comment: Right, not sure it's much better than declaring and invoking a lambda though :)

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune This lets you avoid declaring the lambda, i.e. `Func<...>` stays out of the picture.

Comment: I *thought* of putting that up as an answer, but constructing an intermediate array, iterating over it, then reducing it again to a single element is quite ugly in its inefficiency when consistently applied (which you might do if you think it's neat). And all that to eliminate one *visible* intermediate variable!

Comment: @JeroenMostert I edited to remove intermediate array, using `Repeat` instead.

Comment: Not to spoil the fun, but that's quite possibly worse. `Enumerable.Repeat` allocates a (compiler-implemented) iterator object to implement the enumerable. I imagine that's more costly than a single-element array (but I''ll readily admit I haven't measured). Optimizing this isn't *really* meaningful, of course, but still.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured that a generic extension method could fill the gap:

```
public static class TransformExtension
{
    public static T2 Transform<T1, T2>(this T1 t1, Func<T1, T2> transform)
    {
        return transform(t1);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public class A { };
public class B { };

void Foo()
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = a.Transform(x => new B());
}
```

Happy to hear why that's possibly a terrible idea.

Comment: You don't even need to restrict `T1` and `T2` to a class (see my last edit).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Oh, hadn't seen your edit, I came up with this solution independently... Good point about the constraints, I'll remove them. I'll accept your solution since it's only fair :)